# Output data from mysql using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to view the data on mysql using ajax, im having a problem with my code. This code doesn't alert anything.

index.php

```
<script>
  function forusedata(id) {
    $.post('insert_home.php', {BOOKDATA: id}).done(function(data) {
      alert(data);
    });
  }
</script>
});
```

insert_home.php

```
else if (isset($_POST['BOOKDATA'])) {
  $ENUM = ($_POST['BOOKDATA']);

  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *FROM book WHERE BOOKID='$ENUM'");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['BOOKCAPTION'];
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: Please post the full `<script>` and `PHP` code :). Where is `forusedata()` called?

Comment: Have you checked your data to make sure it's in json format? An alert such as this often just gives [obj]:[obj]. you may need to parse the data.

Comment: The PHP script hasn't all been posted. Please post the rest

Comment: So what part is failing? Have you tried to narrow down the problem?  Is the AJAX posting the data you expect?  Is the DB query returning the results you expect?  Is the PHP script outputting results as you expect? Is the response being received by AJAX with proper 200 status code?

Comment: it doesnt post anything

Comment: is there something wrong on the way i used AJAX?

Comment: please correct this SELECT *FROM book WHERE BOOKID='$ENUM', it should be SELECT * FROM book WHERE BOOKID='$ENUM'

Comment: please disregard the   $('#Page1').dialog('open'); i'll edit it

Comment: first of all:
echo json_encode($row['BOOKCAPTION'])

second:
try to do it like this:
$.post('insert_home.php', {BOOKDATA: id}),function(data){
alert(data);
});

and there needs to be a space between the * and the from.
*from
* from

Comment: what the diffrence? @Neo

Comment: that is a "sql" syntax, you should have a space before FROM keyword.

Comment: Still doesnt work. huhu

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

**script**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Test POST</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $.post(
        'insert_home.php',
        {
          BOOKDATA: 1
        }
      ).done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
      });

    });
  </script>  

</body>
</html>
```

**insert_home.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['BOOKDATA'])) {

  // search user

  echo 'BOOKDATA = ' . $_POST['BOOKDATA'];

}
```

**In you case, you need to transform your mysql result in a text or json format, like** `echo json_encode($your_var);`

---

Your problem maybe is in your `SELECT/mysqli` connection.

Try see the return in you **Developers Tools (Chrome)**:

- Press F12
- Clique in **Network** tab
- Search for your **insert_home.php** request
- Click in **Response**

[image: Chrome Tools - AJAX POST]

---

Hope this helps